# How to enable UDP checksums

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, udp, checksum

I'm working on a project involving UDP socket communication between a VxWorks device and a Linux machine.  In this project, I'd like to take advantage of the checksum field of the UDP header.

It appears that in the VxWorks socket interface, the `checksum` field of outgoing UDP packets is enabled by default.

However, for the usual Unix sockets interface, there doesn't appear to be any flag or other method to open a UDP socket that will check the checksum for incoming packets and populate it for outgoing ones.

For the usual Unix sockets interface, does such a flag exist?

Thanks!

Comment: If it doesn't generate or check the UDP checksum, then it isn't UDP, but something else. Unless you've read in the official docs that vxworks does not check the UDP checksums, it's safe to assume that it does.

Comment: @nos not quiet true. You can turn off generating checksum in interface.

Comment: @UDPLover That turns off CRC generation on the NIC itself, so the OS have to do it instead.

Comment: @nos UDP protocol specifies that checksum field can have value 0, and that means checksum was not generated, and so receiver should not try to check checksum.

Comment: @nos its OS implementation dependent. UDP packet without checksum is also valid packet. It is upto receive application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm no expert, but the only thing that [`man 7 udp`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/udp.7.html) has to say on the matter suggests that it's enabled by default:

> UDP generates and checks checksums to catch transmission errors.

It does not mention any way to disable it.

Edit: I'm too lazy to look up current kernel source, but [this page](http://leapster.org/linux/kernel/udp/#udp_recvmsg) suggests that packets with invalid checksums are simply dropped (the `csum_copy_err` part).

Comment: With UDP over IPv4, the checksum field is technically optional. If the value is 0, checksums are ignored. However, UDP over IPv6 requires the checksum to be non-zero, and datagrams with a zeroed checksum must be discarded. If the checksum *should* be zero, it has to be sent as FFFF. (Look for "UDP checksum" in [RFC 2460](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2460.txt), the RFC that specifies IPv6).

Comment: checksum will be find error? data segment will be drop?? in UDP

Answer (score 4):

(I am not an expert. The following may be completely wrong.)

The network interface (or driver or something equivalent) should be checking the checksums of incoming packets. A checksum of all-bits-zero means "The outgoing interface didn't generate a checksum." The interface MUST check any other checksum (including all-bits-one, a.k.a. "negative zero" in the ones' complement encoding used by the checksum field) and MUST drop the packet if it fails the check.

Therefore, you are *never* allowed to disable UDP checksum *checking* on incoming packets (if those packets have checksums provided, that is). That's just a mandatory part of the UDP standard.

The receiving interface MAY drop packets with no checksum,<sup>[1]</sup> or MAY pass them on to the application (or MAY let the application configure its desired behavior, although if this is possible, I don't know how to do it).

The only thing you might possibly be able to control is whether the sending interface *generates* checksums on *outgoing* packets. It'll be platform-specific. I've collected some ways below, which might or might not work; caveat lector.

If you just take your platform's default behavior, you will get UDP checksum generation by default — I'd put money on it.

> [1] — [RFC 8085](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8085#section-3.4): "An application is permitted to optionally discard UDP datagrams with a zero checksum [[RFC1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-78)]."

---

[This comp.protocols.tcp-ip post from 1999](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.protocols.tcp-ip/YXx6cHkihAU) suggests that on Solaris, you can globally disable the generation of UDP checksums on outgoing packets via [`ndd`](http://www.softpanorama.org/Net/Solaris/ndd.shtml) at the command line:

```
ndd -set /dev/udp udp_do_checksum 0
```

The `ndd` utility is specific to the Solaris kernel, and does not exist on Linux or FreeBSD. Also, even [the Solaris docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/E37386/chapter4-57.html#glfbi) say:

```
udp_do_checksum
  This parameter controls whether UDP calculates the checksum
  on outgoing UDP/IPv4 packets.

Default
  1 (enabled)

When to Change
  Do not change this parameter.
```

(On Linux and FreeBSD, [`/dev/udp` "doesn't really exist"; it's a fiction provided by Bash.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/311099) I don't know whether `/dev/udp` "really exists" on Solaris.)

---

[Microsoft's docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738603(v=vs.85).aspx) imply that on Windows, you can disable UDP checksum generation programmatically on a per-socket basis, using a documented option:

```cpp
DWORD trueValue = 1;
int rc = setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_UDP, UDP_NOCHECKSUM, (const char*)&yes, sizeof yes);
if (rc != 0) { perror("setsockopt"); abort(); }
```

---

[This thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/71824) implies that on FreeBSD (e.g. Mac OS X) you can disable checksum generation programmatically on a per-socket basis, using an otherwise undocumented (but present as of January 2018) option:

```cpp
int yes = 1;
int rc = setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_UDP, UDP_NOCKSUM, (void*)&yes, sizeof yes);
if (rc != 0) { perror("setsockopt"); abort(); }
```

---

And finally, [this thread](https://linux-tips.com/t/how-to-disable-udp-checksum-control-in-kernel/362) implies that on Linux you can disable checksum generation programmatically on a per-socket basis, using an otherwise undocumented (but present as of January 2018) option:

```cpp
int yes = 1;
int rc = setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NO_CHECK, (void*)&yes, sizeof yes);
if (rc != 0) { perror("setsockopt"); abort(); }
```

---

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the comment by @zneak, [RFC6936](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6936.txt) now allows the use of UDP zero checksums over IPv6 under some restricted conditions, such as for tunneled traffic. Linux defines the `UDP_NO_CHECK6_TX` and `UDP_NO_CHECK6_RX` socket options for this, see [this commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/1c19448c9ba6545b80ded18488a64a7f3d8e6998).