# Is it possible to create a UDP socket without checksum?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp, oserror

I’m having some trouble with an assignment for my university. The idea behind the assignment is to learn how TCP works by implementing a basic variant called bTCP in Python (3.9.10). Super awesome, but it just won’t work. The whole problem comes down to this function:

```py
class LossyLayer:

    def __init__(self, btcp_socket, local_ip, local_port, remote_ip, remote_port):

        self._bTCP_socket   = btcp_socket
        self._remote_ip     = remote_ip
        self._remote_port   = remote_port

        self._udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self._udp_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        # Disable UDP checksum generation (and by extension, checking) s.t.
        # corrupt packets actually make it to the bTCP layer.
        # socket.SO_NO_CHECK is not defined in Python, so hardcode the value
        # from /usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h:#define SO_NO_CHECK = 11.
        self._udp_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 11, 1)
        self._udp_socket.bind((local_ip, local_port))

        self._event     = threading.Event()
        self._thread    = threading.Thread(
            target      = handle_incoming_segments,
            args        = (self._bTCP_socket, self._event, self._udp_socket))

        self._thread.start()

    # some other less relevant functions
    # ...
```

The idea is to create a so called “lossy layer” that interacts with the layer below bTCP, but we emulate the actual network over UDP. So, I set the class' `socket`, `remote_ip` and `remote_port` to some value. Right after that, I create the actual UDP socket and enable reuse of the address. Then I want to disable the standard checksum validation, but I get the following error:

`OSError: [Errno 42] Protocol not available`

The code provided above is exactly stated in the assignment. I do not have to change the code to be able to get everything working, so I was wondering if my MacBook (with macOS Monterey 12.2.1) does (not) support this setting. Is this correct, or am I overlooking something? Is it even possible for macOS (because operating system restrictions) to get a UDP socket with the SO_NO_CHECK working?

I’m really curious why it doesn’t work. Hopefully someone can help solving the riddle soon!

Comment: Do you really need to disable checksumming?  If your motivation is that you want to verify that the receiving side can handle corrupted packets appropriately, you could simulate that corruption by having the receiver occasionally write random data into a just-received UDP packet payload.  I'd think that would be easier than trying to convince MacOS to disable UDP checksum-verification -- especially since you'd probably find out that the Layer-2/Ethernet layer is doing its own checksumming anyway, and so you *still* wouldn't receive any corrupted packets.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, yes I want to disable the internet checksum, because I have implemented it myself (as described in the assignment)

Comment: https://www.unix.com/programming/67003-disabling-ip-checksum-calculation.html

Comment: I have no direct knowledge, but this might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48068443/1076479. It suggests that there is a different option in mac os.

Comment: You can't rely on option values &c. being the same across different operating systems. You will have to look up `SO_NO_CHECK` in the MacOS include files.